# Python xpath - how to get textcontent from node?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to convert a script from PHP (which I know well) to Python (which I am just learning).

Conceptually, I use an xpath selector to find a node from a DOM tree which I construct using html.fromstring. This gets me, example, a reference to a "TD" node from a table.

In PHP, I can then use $node->item(0)->textContent to get whatever the text is in that node, regardless of any other markup. This is helpful because sometimes there are other HTML tags - font, b, p, etc., and the pattern where the text ends up isn't consistent.

In Python, I use the following syntax:

`text = row.xpath("./td[1]/text()")`

However that comes back as matching nothing. If I omit the /text(), it matches the node, and if I try and print the node, I get something like [] - so it's clearly an object, not a string.

if I use this syntax:

`text = row.xpath("./td[1]/b/font/p/text()")`

This **does** get me the text (in list format), however the HTML is not always bolded, and is not always within a font tag.

So my question is, how can I get *any* text that is within the selected object?

Comment: It would be helpful , if you can give example of site. 
Also, it highly depends on which python module you are using to create DOM, like beautifulsoup or scrapy or lxml. 
And, here if 
text = row.xpath("./td[1]/b/font/p/text()") is working then, to avoid bold and font inconsistency, you can generalize your xpath as "row.xpath("./td[1]//text()")". But since site is not given, I cannot try it out. Please check it out yourself, if this works.

Comment: Thank you - you solved the problem by pointing out to me that I can use a double-slash in the selector to represent "anything between".